# Delete data from multiple table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, security

I am using delete query in codeigniter to delete same ID datas from multiple table

my query

```
public function delete_customer($id)
{
    $this->db->where('cus_id',$id);
    $this->db->delete('tbl_customer'); 
    $this->db->where('customer_id',$id);
    $this->db->delete('tbl_additional_details');
    $this->db->where('customer_id',$id);
    $this->db->delete('tbl_amc_supervisor');
    $this->db->where('cr_customer_id',$id);
    $this->db->delete('tbl_current_issues');
    $this->db->where('customer_id',$id);
    $this->db->delete('tbl_pickmachine');
    $this->db->where('customer_id',$id);
    $this->db->delete('tbl_sales');
    $this->db->where('customer_id',$id);
    $this->db->delete('tbl_service');
    return true;
}
```

any way to simplify and secur this query ..

Comment: You can used with transaction rollback feature.

Comment: Easier way would be define FKs for customer relations with cascade delete and just perform delete query on table `tbl_customer`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid any other way?

Comment: @NikuNjRathod some time $id not in all table they only two or three table only

Comment: if they have relationship, alter table and make it update or delete cascade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way would be use a joined query to delete from multiple tables something like

```
DELETE 
  c,
  d,
  s,
  i,
  m,
  sa,
  se 
FROM
  tbl_customer c 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_additional_details d 
    ON (c.cus_id = d.customer_id) 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_amc_supervisor s 
    ON (c.cus_id = s.customer_id) 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_current_issues i 
    ON (c.cus_id = i.cr_customer_id) 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_pickmachine m 
    ON (c.cus_id = m.customer_id) 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_sales sa 
    ON (c.cus_id = sa.customer_id) 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_service se 
    ON (c.cus_id = se.customer_id) 
WHERE c.cus_id = @id
```

> Note do take the backup of your data before you execute similar query

Comment: IF ANY ONE MISS THIS QUERY EXICUTED

Comment: @andrewghosh I am unable to get your comment * 
IF ANY ONE MISS THIS QUERY EXICUTED* can you elaborate it more ?

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid If $id not in tbl_sales the query will executed or show error

Comment: @andrewghosh Nope, You can see i have used LEFT join not inner. You have to test this query on some demo data set first

Comment: @M khalid Junaid Working tkz

Answer (score 0):

Better use stored procedures inside that, you can incorporate commit and rollback. Stored procedures are faster and safe because it prevents SQl injection